# Best way to emit integer pairs in range with step bigger than 1

Tags: java, rx-java2

I would like to process ranges of integers in rxjava2 and I'm looking for most elegant way to solve it. Brute force solution (`processRange` function is just a placeholder, in reality it is a lot more complex thing working on from/to variables - you can think about it as a paging thing from database, which needs to be accessed in specific size chunks to be performant):

```java
public static Flowable<Object> processRange(int from, int to) {
    return Flowable.just("From:" + from + " to:" + to);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int start = 333;
    int end = 78777;
    int step = 1000;

    List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> ranges = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (int i = start; i < end; i += step) {
        ranges.add(Pair.of(i, Math.min(i + step - 1, end)));
    }

    Flowable.concat(
            ranges.stream()
                    .map(range -> processRange(range.getLeft(), range.getRight())).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

I think it is really ugly way of achieving it. I came up with something which reuses a bit of rxjava, but it is still quite verbose and cryptic

```java
    int start = 333;
    int end = 78777;
    int step = 1000;

    int count = (end-start-1)/step + 1;

    Flowable.concat(
            Flowable.range(0,count)
                    .map(idx -> processRange(start+idx*step,Math.min(start+((idx+1)*step)-1,end))))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Worst case scenario, I will just hide it all inside a method and unit test the hell out of it, but maybe I'm prying an open door here and there is something simpler available?

Comment: Why do you use RxJava? Do you want to stream the values async, or do you want to calc the values sync.? To me it looks like you try to generate some values and print them out, no need to use RxJava here.

Comment: It is just an example. In real use case, processRange method returns Flowable (and it is a third party library). And yes, idea is to do it asynchronously, so processRange for next range is not really called before previous items are consumed (that part works).

Answer (score 1):

You could use for example `create()` operator:

```java
class SO65163142 {
    public Flowable<String> processRange(int from, int to) {
        return Flowable.just("From:" + from + " to:" + to);
    }

    public Flowable<String> getRanges(int start, int end, int step) {
        return Flowable
                .create((FlowableOnSubscribe<Pair<Integer, Integer>>) emitter -> {
                    int current = start;

                    while (current + step < end) {
                        emitter.onNext(new Pair<>(current, current + step - 1));
                        current += step;
                    }

                    emitter.onNext(new Pair<>(current, end));
                    emitter.onComplete();
                }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                .flatMap(pair -> processRange(pair.first, pair.second));
    }
}
```

Make sure you apply some +/-1 offsets based on your needs. Some verification:

```java
public class SO65163142Test {

    @Test
    public void getRangesTest() {
        SO65163142 tested = new SO65163142();

        int start = 333;
        int end = 4777;
        int step = 1000;

        TestSubscriber<String> testSubscriber = tested
                .getRanges(start, end, step)
                .test();

        testSubscriber.assertValues(
                "From:333 to:1332",
                "From:1333 to:2332",
                "From:2333 to:3332",
                "From:3333 to:4332",
                "From:4333 to:4777"
        );
    }
}
```